# Status check after one year in beta

Tags: discussion

Emacs.SE has now been in Beta for one full year (birthday cake)!

For users: what outstanding issues (long-running, or recently-arising) are there that we could do to improve?

For the powers that be: could we get a sense of where the site stands, and when we might find out if it will graduate?

Answer (score 14):

I'll only chime in wrt issues: it would've been great if we had Org source code highlighting. I'm not sure what needs to be done, but I'm quite sure there is code in the wild to do that.

Comment: As I understand, SX uses [google prettify](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), and that does not seem to support Org.  That said, it would be a great feature to have :).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [Happy Birthday](http://xkcd.com/1581/)! It's been an amazing year of growth. My heartfelt congratulations to you all.

As for graduation, at [11.1 questions a day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76571/emacs), Emacs meets the [new quantitative criterion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/1438) for graduation. This means that graduation ([sans a new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation)) is on the table. We've done a quality check and I fully expect that we'll be announcing a moderator election in the very near future.

In the meantime, I hope that you all will continue the good work that you've started and look forward to years of answered Emacs questions to come.

Answer (score 1):

Really great to have emacs.SE.  It seems like most of my emacs Google questions are still directed towards SO, but that should change as this site matures.