# Vote in the 2018 moderator election!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

#### We have an [election for a new moderator](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) going on right now.

Check out [the candidates' answers to the Q&A](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1), and then [go vote!](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)